# Windows 7 on Laptop: Show 3 power Profiles instead of just 2

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

The only thing I miss from Vista on W7 is that, you can click the batery icon and select one of three power profiles without having to open the Energy option Window.

Can I archieve this on W7 Without having to install a third party tool? I have tried one, but with so many bugs and problems, but I guess there are maybe one tool out there that works fine.

I'm Using W7 Professional x64

Thanks in advance

Comment: hy do you need three? Use two. Dynamic for the performance (makes sense to use it dynamic not EVERYTHING on full), low power for battery saving. In my opinion this is the best / only usable way, full perf won't give any advantage just kills / overheats / heats your laptop. (At least I didn't find any point in using that on a laptop.)

Comment: @Shiki Not true (at least, not on my laptop). The dynamic/balanced mode won't fully crank up the video card on my laptop - I have to use high performance to get maximum 3d performance or to play blurays without skipping, even on mains power.

Comment: Makes sense for me, because I need those two you mention(power saver and dinamic), but also I need one for full power and no sleep, on some moments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, however, you can use the `WIN+X` keyboard shortcut to bring up the Windows Mobility Center which lets you switch between your power profiles from a drop down list.